# Thread dump on android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am developing an android application on android.
Is it possible (via DDMS or adb shell) for me to do a thread dump of all the threads of my application?

Comment: when you run in eclipse in debug mode, all the threads in your app are listed as they are created and delisted when destroyed.  Is this not what you mean by a thread dump?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what ddms supports, via the adb shell you can run

```
ps -t
```

or

```
top -t
```

While most android shell commands are primitive and take only a subset of standard options, top seems to have some built in help it prints when bad options are given, ps did not, but fortunately its source code is available to examine.

Comment: Wow, I just installed a Busybox onto my Android phone and had everything :D

Comment: Sure, but the above two capabilities are in stock android